# Where does this CI for Proportion formula come from?

Tags: probability, statistics, confidence-interval

In College, I was taught that the CI for proportion is as follows.

$$ \left( \ \overline{\!X}\:\pm \frac{1}{2\sqrt{n\cdot \alpha }} \right) $$

But this is very far from the one that is commonly known, that is

$$
\hat{p}\:\pm z * \ \sqrt\frac{p(1-p)}{n}
$$

Can anyone please elaborate where does the first CI come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first expression, I am not sure what $\alpha$ is  or why the $2$ remains in the denominator

In your second expression, I think you are missing a square root so might be looking at $$\hat{p}\:\pm z \sqrt{ \frac{p(1-p)}{n}}$$

The second part of that is maximised when $p=\frac12$ making $p(1-p)=\frac14$ and $\sqrt{ \frac{p(1-p)}{n}} =\frac1{2\sqrt{n}}$

If $z \approx 1.96$ based on a $95\%$ two-tailed confidence interval for a normal distribution and you round this to $2$, and you use the natural estimator $\hat p=\bar X$, you would get $$\bar X \pm \frac1{\sqrt{n}}$$

This may be unnecessarily wide when $p$ is not close to $\frac12$ but at least is conservative.  Depending on your point of view, it is simple or crude and there may be more sophisticated methods for [binomial proportion confidence intervals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval) when $n$ is small